# what is the purpose of BufferOverflowException

Tags: queue

I don't quite understand the meaning/purpose of the BufferOverflowException(); 
In my course we're using it to code a queue and whilst adding elements to the queue we're using the BufferOverflowException.

According to docs.oracle it means "Unchecked exception thrown when a relative put operation reaches the target buffer's limit." and still I don't understand the meaning of it.

```
public class FIFOQueue<T>{
T[] data;
int first=0; 
int last=0; 
boolean full = false; 

public FIFOQueue(int capacity){
    data = (T[]) new Object[capacity];
}

public void add(T element){
    if (full)
        throw new BufferOverflowException();
    data[last] = element;
    last++;
    if (last == data.length)
        last = 0;
    if (last == first)
        full = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffer Overflow means that **too much data** is given to an application.

Example: Copy the text of a book into 'New Contact Name' on a phone.

Typically, if not handled well, this leads to a **chrash**...
More importantly, it can be a **security flaw**!

The extra data can get stored outside of the programs designated memory, and the extra data could be executable code.

So, it's good practice to always validate user input! :)